# inArray() returns false all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm not sure how to fix it, but I always get `-1` when using `inArray()`. To be more explicit, here's what I'm doing :

```
<!-- HTML Markup -->

<nav class="navigation clearfix">
    <a class="home-anchor" data-class="home-anchor" href="#">
        <span class="icons-wrapper">
            <i class="icon-normal-state"></i>
            <i class="icon-active-state"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="anchor-text">Home</span>
    </a>
    <a class="about-anchor" data-class="about-anchor" href="#">
        <span class="icons-wrapper">
            <i class="icon-normal-state"></i>
            <i class="icon-active-state"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="anchor-text">About</span>
    </a>
    <a class="work-anchor" data-class="work-anchor" href="#">
        <span class="icons-wrapper">
            <i class="icon-normal-state"></i>
            <i class="icon-active-state"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="anchor-text">Work</span>
    </a>
    <a class="shop-anchor" data-class="shop-anchor" href="#">
        <span class="icons-wrapper">
            <i class="icon-normal-state"></i>
            <i class="icon-active-state"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="anchor-text">Shop</span>
    </a>
    <a class="services-anchor" data-class="services-anchor" href="#">
        <span class="icons-wrapper">
            <i class="icon-normal-state"></i>
            <i class="icon-active-state"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="anchor-text">Services</span>
    </a>
    <a class="contact-anchor" data-class="contact-anchor" href="#">
        <span class="icons-wrapper">
            <i class="icon-normal-state"></i>
            <i class="icon-active-state"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="anchor-text">Contact</span>
    </a>
</nav>

/* JavaScript Markup */

var anchors = $(this.cluster_navigation_class).children();
var anchor = (jQuery.inArray(data, anchors) == -1) ? anchors[0] : jQuery.inArray(data, anchors);
```

Where `this.cluster_navigation_class` is `.navigation`, and `data` is `.about-anchor`. The JavaScript statement above always returns `-1` when I check in console, why is that happening ? Shouldn't it return the index `1` because the class exists at the index `1`, or am I wrong ?

Comment: sory, where is definition of "data"?

Comment: It doesn't check the class. It checks the values of objects. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: And how would I check the class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `inArray` wrong. You are comparing a string to a list of elements. jQuery can not magically know what you want to do.

Do you realize you contrdict yourself in your post. One place you are saying checking data and next place you are saying checking class. The data and class are just repeated, so I am not sure what is the problem using either of them.

You should be using `find` to select the element inside of the navigation element.

```
var myLink = jQuery(".navigation").find('[data-class="about-anchor"]');
```

Another way to use filter:

```
var links = jQuery(".navigation a");
var activeElem = links.filter( function(){ return jQuery(this).data()==="about-anchor"; } ); 
var myLink = activeElem.length===1 ? activeElem : links.eq(0);
```

or with the class

```
var links = jQuery(".navigation a");
var activeElem = links.filter(".about-anchor");
var myLink = activeElem.length===1 ? activeElem : links.eq(0);
```

Comment: But I'm not looking for that. I'm looking for a class ( saved on localStorage ) to match one of the classes in the navigation. And if it's not found I just return the first navigation item ( home in my case ) which would be the index page when landing on the website.

Comment: So look for data, changed the selector.

Comment: So @epascarello, let me put it another way, how do I store all the classes of the children of that navigation inside an array ? That way I can use `inArray()`, because I need that class, not the element. Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Why do you need that class? Reasoning?

Comment: Because I'm using it in other functions, what I pasted is only a small part of all the code block I'm developing. But main reason is because I'm storing it via localStorage and reuse it when you come back on the page.

Comment: My code basically returns the same thing yours does! It returns the element that matches, if not it returns the first. Try it out.

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't work :) It still return the same thing, the first child of the navigation

Comment: I fixed it by removing the function inside the `.filter()` and comparing against the class directly. Thanks :)